# Google Apps Script in Google Doc - How to merge 2 format in 1 paragraph

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

How do I combine both into 1 paragraph instead but with different formatting?  Something like concatenate?

```html
function insertControlPara() {
  var paraControlStyle1 = {};
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 11;
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY;
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 1.5;
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_BEFORE] = 10;

  var paraControlStyle2 = {};
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 8;
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY;
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 1.5;
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_BEFORE] = 10;
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#980000';

  var text1 = body.setText('Paragraph <Normal Text, Calibri, 11PT, 1.5 Spacing, Space before Paragraph> ');
  var text2 = body.setText('Paragraph <Normal Text, Calibri, 8PT, 1.5 Spacing, Space before Paragraph> ');
  var paraText = text1 + text2;
  body.appendParagraph(paraText);
}
```

The result should be this:
[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between `How do I combine both into 1 paragraph instead but with different formatting? Something like concatenate?` and your showing script?

Comment: sorry, I want to combine para1 and para2 into 1 paragraph in Google Doc.  Is there a syntax code for that? In spreadsheet we can use concatenate but in Google Doc?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from `I want to combine para1 and para2 into 1 paragraph in Google Doc. Is there a syntax code for that? In spreadsheet we can use concatenate but in Google Doc?`, I couldn't still understand the relationship between `How do I combine both into 1 paragraph instead but with different formatting? Something like concatenate?` and your showing script.

Comment: Sorry @Tanaike.  I have update the code snippet.  The problem is I cannot combine text1 + text2.  Not sure if this is clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the function merge()

Using the `merge()` function concatenates the second paragraph with the previous paragraph. Appending two existing paragraphs, like in your case, requires the usage of the function `getChild()`. In your case, you may use the following script:

```
function insertControlPara() {
  var paraControlStyle1 = {};
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 11;
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY;
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 1.5;
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_BEFORE] = 10;

  var paraControlStyle2 = {};
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 8;
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY;
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 1.5;
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_BEFORE] = 10;
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#980000';

  //Changes start here
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var par1 = body.getChild(0); //assigns the first paragraph to par1
  var par2 = body.getChild(1); //assigns the second paragraph to par2
  par1.setAttributes(paraControlStyle1);
  par2.setAttributes(paraControlStyle2);
  par2.merge(); //merges the two paragraphs

}
```

In this modified script, I used the following test case:

[image: test data]

Wherein `Test 1` will be referred to as `par1` and `Test 2` will be referred to as `par2` in the script. After storing the paragraphs in their respective variables using the `getChild` function, the `setAttributes()` function was applied based on your settings before merging the paragraphs using the `merge()` function. The output should look like this:

[image: output]

Please take note that there should be no new line between both paragraphs before merging since the new line will also be counted as a child.

[image: sample]

### References:

- [getChild()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getchildchildindex)
- [merge()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#merge)

### Additional Information:

When using the function `appendParagraph()` on an empty document, the function adds another child. Hence, the empty entity will be counted as the first child (child(0)) while the appended paragraph will be counted as the second child (child(1)). Hence, the usage of the function `removeChild()` is needed. In this case, you may modify the script this way:

```
function insertControlPara() {
  var paraControlStyle1 = {};
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 11;
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY;
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 1.5;
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_BEFORE] = 10;
  paraControlStyle1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#000000';

  var paraControlStyle2 = {};
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 8;
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY;
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 1.5;
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_BEFORE] = 10;
  paraControlStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#980000';
  
  //changes start here
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

  var text1 = body.appendParagraph('Test1').setAttributes(paraControlStyle1);
  var text2 = body.appendParagraph('Test2').setAttributes(paraControlStyle2);
  body.removeChild(body.getChild(0)); //remove empty child
  var par1 = body.getChild(0); //first paragraph
  var par2 = body.getChild(1); //second paragraph

  par2.merge();

}
```

Which will result to:

[image: test]

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have other questions with respect to the issue at hand.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickdC.  I encountered error:  Exception: Child index (1) must be less than the number of child elements (1)

Comment: Please take note that the child index starts with index 0. I believe the error occurs when there is only 1 paragraph or the two paragraphs are already merged. I encountered the issue when I ran the script twice given that I only have two paragraphs.

Comment: Noted.  But if I want to pre-insert certain text and set that as para1 and para2?  I tried   var text1 = body.appendParagraph('Test1').setAttributes(paraControlStyle1);
  var text2 = body.appendParagraph('Test2').setAttributes(paraControlStyle2);
  var par1 = body.getChild(0); //assigns the first paragraph to par1
  var par2 = body.getChild(1); //assigns the second paragraph to par2
  par2.merge(); //merges the two paragraphs
Not seems to working on the merge part.

Comment: Let me look into this. The script that I have provided works when the paragraphs are already present in the document.

Comment: You can also post this as another question since you have not added the append function in your original question.

Comment: noted.  Actually my code contains

  var text1 = body.setText('Paragraph <Normal Text, Calibri, 11PT, 1.5 Spacing, Space before Paragraph> ');
  var text2 = body.setText('Paragraph <Normal Text, Calibri, 8PT, 1.5 Spacing, Space before Paragraph> ');
  var paraText = text1 + text2;
Which I was trying to combine(merge) so guess I use the wrong syntax.  If it helps with posting another thread, I can do it.

Comment: I have added the `Additional Information` section for the necessary modification. Apparently, `appendParagraph` adds another child and will not replace the empty child.

Comment: Added `removeChild()` function to remove the empty child.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer to your question is to use the merge method.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73808046/7215091)